# How to match newlines inside (possibly nested) parentheses? (regex)

Tags: php, regex

I am using PHP regex.
Consider a text like this:

```
Lorem ipsum (dolor sit 
amet (consectetur adipiscing
 elit) sed do eiusmod) tempor 
(incididunt) ut 
labore.
```

I need to match the newlines inside the brackets, but not the ones outside brackets (like the last two). My current regex looks like this: `/\([^)]*([\r\n]+)[^(]*\)/s`, however it doesn't capture the newline between "sit" and "amet" because of the nested brace. Can I make it work with regex only, or do I have to parse the text manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may match all the nested parentheses with a recursive regex and then remove all CRLF sequences in the match values inside `preg_replace_callback`.

Use [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/cF8jD3/1) to match nested parentheses:

```
'~\((?>[^()]++|(?R))*\)~'
```

And here is a [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/1XWVOS):

```
$re = '~\((?>[^()]++|(?R))*\)~'; 
$str = "Lorem ipsum (dolor sit \r\namet (consectetur adipiscing\r\n elit) sed do eiusmod) tempor \r\n(incididunt) ut \r\nlabore."; 
$output = preg_replace_callback($re, function($m) {
    return str_replace("\r\n", "", $m[0]);
}, $str);
echo $output;
```

Output:

```
Lorem ipsum (dolor sit amet (consectetur adipiscing elit) sed do eiusmod) tempor 
(incididunt) ut 
labore.
```

Additionally, see [*`Recursive patterns`*](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php) at php.net.

Comment: Perfect answer, exactly what I needed to learn about! Thanks a lot :)